# Login form not redirecting to home page - even though login credentials appear to match those in database

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

I've got a login-form that is supposed to redirect to the homepage of my React app, if the user's login detail match those already in the MongoDB database (I've got a seperate sign-up form that is working fine).

The issue is, when I'm testing out my login-form, and purposefully typing in credentials that don't match what's in my database, I get this error :

Login.js:44          POST http://localhost:3001/login 401 (Unauthorized)

However, when I type in credentials that do exist - that error no longer appears, but I get the console.log error I've set up - ("login failed")

Why am I getting this error, instead of the app redirecting to the homepage?

It's clearly able to connect to the database and check if the login details stored in there match the user's input.

What else could be causing this issue?

I've also tried altering the url endpoints, but no luck.

This is the login form code

```
import React from "react";
import Input from "./Input";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from "yup";
import {      
  useLocation,
  useNavigate,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";


function withRouter(Component) {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props) {
    let location = useLocation();
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let params = useParams();
    return (
      <Component
        {...props}
        router={{ location, navigate, params }}
      />
    );
  }

  return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}

const schema = yup.object({
  username: yup.string().required("Username is a required field"),
  password: yup.string().min(6, "Password must be at least 6 characters"),
});

function Login(props) {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    register,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });

  const formSubmit = (data) => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/login", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({username: data.username, password: data.password}),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 200 && props.history) {
        props.history.push("/");
      } else {
        console.log("login failed");
      }
    })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="sign-up">
      <h1>Log in</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur</p>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(formSubmit)}>
        <Input
          id="username"
          label="Username"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter Username"
          register={{ ...register("username") }}
          errorMessage={errors.username?.message}
        />
    
        <Input
          id="password"
          label="Password"
          type="password"
          placeholder="Enter Password"
          register={{ ...register("password") }}
          errorMessage={errors.password?.message}
        />

        <button>Log in</button>
      </form>
      <button className="button-link" onClick={() => props.onFormSwitch("signup")}>
        Don't have an account? Register here.
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(Login);
```

And this is the server-side

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const Signup = require("./db/dbModel");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
mongoose.connect("..removed for StackOverflow Question");
app.use("/", require("./routes/signupRoute"));
app.use(session({ secret: "secret", resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(
  'local',
  new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {

    Signup.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false);
      }
      if (user.password != password) {
        return done(null, false);
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  })
);

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  Signup.findById(id, (err, user) => {
    done(err, user);
  });
});


app.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {  // test tomorrow
  passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: "Incorrect username or password" });
    }
    req.logIn(user, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      return res.status(200).json({ message: "Successfully logged in" });
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});


/*
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
  successRedirect: "/",
  failureRedirect: "/login",
  failureFlash: true
}));

*/


app.listen(3001, function () {
  console.log("express server is running on port 3001");

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the function in the login form to this.

```
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/login", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ username: data.username, password: data.password }),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          props.router.navigate("/");
        } else {
          console.log("login failed");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
    console.log(data);
  };
```

For some reason, the props.history.push was causing the error - so it's been altered to props.router.navigate